# Setting up Neo4j HA on three instances

Tags: neo4j

I have setup neo4j HA in 3 different VMs (each with 4 cpu's) as per [this link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html). I have setup for production cluster only.
I have started all the 3 instances and imported some sample database in one of the machines, but i can't see that imported database in other two machines.
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Please post your HA configuration

Comment: **Node 1 details**
ha.server_id = 1;
ha.initial_hosts = 10.180.22.38:5001,10.180.22.39:5001,10.180.22.42:5001
**Node 2 details**
ha.server_id = 2;
ha.initial_hosts = 10.180.22.38:5001,10.180.22.39:5001,10.180.22.42:5001
**Node 3 details**
ha.server_id = 3;
ha.initial_hosts = 10.180.22.38:5001,10.180.22.39:5001,10.180.22.42:5001

In neo4j-server property file, I have enabled HA and mentioned respective machine IP for org.neo4j.server.webserver.address

Comment: Have you queried their endpoints to see if they're up and running correctly? http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.2/ha-rest-info.html

Comment: All the machines are up and are running. I have queried in the machine on which i have imported sample database. It is giving outputs. But on the remaining machines, the database nodes are not seen, means replication on other two machines has not happened at all.

Comment: What about /db/manage/server/ha/available on the slaves? Are they available?

Comment: Ya Luanne, You are right. I have trying to access my neo4j from browser **http://00.00.00.00:7474/db/manage/server/ha/master**
It is showing the following error
`{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed",
    "message" : "No authorization header supplied."
  } ]
}`
What does it mean? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do i check /db/manage/server/ha/available on slaves?

Comment: Using curl. See the examples in the link above. For auth issues, see http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.2/rest-api-security.html

Comment: i  have disabled authentication by setting to false the dbms.security.auth_enabled property in <neo4j-install-dir>/conf/neo4j-server.properties, and then restarted the server.

Comment: Hi everyone,  Can anyone share the simple procedure to set neo4j HA. I am giving my HA configuration on 3 machines. Do i have to mention any other parameters also? Kindly suggest
**Node 3 Details** `ha.server_id = 3

ha.cluster_server=10.180.22.42:5001

ha.server=10.180.22.42:6001

ha.initial_hosts = 10.180.22.38:5001,10.180.22.39:5001,10.180.22.42:5001`  
I have mentioned respective server_id and IP for other two nodes.
Any will be greatly appreciated